# web2py anyserver.py. How to pass gunicorn parameter

Tags: gunicorn, web2py

at the moment our production sever runs the following command:

```
python anyserver.py -s gunicorn -i 127.0.0.1 -p 8000 --workers=9
```

i need to pass the gunicorn parameter "timeout INT" (https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html)

if i do :

```
python anyserver.py -s gunicorn -i 127.0.0.1 -p 8000 --workers=9 --timeout 120
```

i get the error:

```
anyserver.py: error: no such option: --timeout
```

How can i pass the gunicorn timeout parameter  into the anyserver.py script?

Answer (score 0):

I know that it is an old post but passing the parameter with just "-t" might help the others looking for an answer.

Can you try it like

```
python anyserver.py -s gunicorn -i 127.0.0.1 -p 8000 --workers=9 -t 120
```